# JQuery script to fill textbox / input based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to craft a JQuery script to fill all textboxes on a page with a single string of text.

The textboxes on this page have no name or ID, so I need to fill them in by class.

```
<td>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Optional Comment" value="" style="">
</td>
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: check this link [how to use Jquery Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp); For example: JQuery Selector for Class: $(".intro") = [All elements with class="intro"]

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with vanilla JS DOM manipulation?

```
var allTextboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".CLASS_SELECTOR");

for(var i = 0, len = allTextboxes.length; i < len; i++){
    allTextboxes[i].value = "YOUR_VALUE";
}
```

Comment: No, I'm pretty new to JQuery. So, based on what you posted, would this be correct?   ------    

var allTextboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".input");

for(var i = 0, len = allTextboxes.length; i < len; i++){
    allTextboxes[i].value = "TEST TEST";
}

Comment: @zreilly Definitely it should.

Comment: Did not fill the textboxes on my page unfortunately.

Comment: @zreilly Please post a jsfiddle/jsbin